# Apply function to a column in RDD (python, spark)

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

This is my RDD:

```
id|               arr |
+--------------------+-
|1|  [8,5,1,11,10,8,2]|
|2|    [3,6,3,1,0,1,2]|
|3|    [4,2,2,0,1,1,3]|
|4|    [0,0,0,0,0,2,0]|
|5|    [3,4,7,3,2,1,2]|
|6|    [1,0,1,0,6,0,0]|
|7|    [2,1,2,2,9,3,0]|
|8|    [3,2,2,3,1,0,3]|
|9| [1,1,7,12,11,5,5]|
```

I am looking how can I apply a function that sums all the numbers in a list and returns sum in a separate column. This is my function (I use python). It works on one array but I have no idea how to apply it to a column in RDD.

```
def sum_func(x):
  t = 0
  for i in range(0, len(x)):
    t = t + x[i]
  return t == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply it to a column on your dataframe, you may create and apply a User Defined Function(UDF).

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

def sum_func(x):
  t = 0
  for i in range(0, len(x)):
    t = t + x[i]
  return t

# Creating the UDF with return type Integer

sum_func_udf = udf(sum_func,IntegerType())
```

Then on your dataframe (let say it is stored in `df`), we use the `withColumn` to add another column

```py
df = df.withColumn(
   sum_func_udf(df.arr).alias("sum")
)
```